# проверка кук и поисковые роботы (+CSRF +$_POST + потеря $_GET) проверка поддержки сессий

Tags: php, http, cookie, сессия, проверка

(изменил заголовок вопроса, потому что тема более объемная)

---

Есть такое (вначале каждой страницы, кроме стр сообщения об ошибке):

```
function cooki_check() {
@session_start();

if (!isset($_COOKIE['ct'])) {
    //если неустановлена, то устанвоить
    setcookie("ct", 1);
    //и сообщить "обновите стнраницу или вкл куки"
    er(1);
    }
}
```

При первом обращении к сайту всегда будет такая "проблема". Другие способы проверки пробовал, но такой самый эффективный (и самый тупо-неправильный). Почему именно так? Потому что для некоторых страниц "классический" способ проверки не подходит.

*Хотя... кто (что) мешает мне использовать два способа проверки для разных страниц? Ну я еще точно не определился что и как.*

Если робот-поисовик будет смотреть на страницу, то сначала он получит страницу ошибки. И если продолжит далее индексировать содержание (при условии что для робота кука установится), то будет все нормально.

---

Вопрос вот в чем: Не получится ли так, что все страницы сайта будут выглядеть для поискового робота как страница ошибки `Обновите страницу или вкл куки в браузере`

---

Почему "классическая" проверка не подходит. Потому что в ней есть редирект на `PHP_SELF`. Теряются `$_GET` параметры. Проблему "потери" гет переметров я решил, НО при отключенных куках проверка не всегда срабатывает так как нужно и получается ай-яй-йяй. Ниже то что я обозвал "классической проверкой".

```
function cooki_check() { 
    @session_start();

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['ct']) and ! isset($_GET['ct'])) {
    //неустановл ни кука, ни гет - первое обращение к странице

    setcookie('ct', 1);
    //установить куку и гет параметр и редир не себя
    header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?ct=1");
    exit;
        } elseif (!isset($_COOKIE['ct'])) {
        //если в первом ифе установлен гет параметр, то это НЕ первое обращение к странице. проверяем куку. если неустаовленна то 100% ошибка.
        er(1);
        //ошибка
   }
}
```

---

О потере каких-таких параметров я написал выше: Например пользователь щелкает в почтовом клиенте на ссылке подтверждения регистрации. А в скрипте делается редирект на PHP_SELF. Таким образом гет-переметры, необходимые для подтверждения регистрации *пропадают. Но я это как-бэ решил.*

Comment: Думаю использовать оба варианта - один для одних страниц, второй для других страниц. Это будет то что нужно.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще это делаете? Если куки не установлено, вы там что-то в единицу ставите. Ну так и работайте дальше со страницей, будто куки уже была и установлена в единицу. В чем проблема то?

Comment: ??? а как же сессия?

Comment: Устанавливаю в 1, для того чтобы при проверках на других страницах НЕ выводилось сообщщение о необходимоссти обновить страницу или разрешить\включить куки в браузере. Надеюсь вы меня не спросите зачем мне вообще нужно проверять куку.

Comment: Тогда извиняюсь. неправильно понял вопрос. Честно говоря я бы вообще посоветовал вам пересмотреть этот подход. Заходишь на сайт и сразу обновите страницу? Чет не хорошо. Запилите уже JS скрипт проверяющий установилось куки (хотя если у человека выключены куки может и JS быть выключен) и делающий редирект, если нет. или просто добавьте проверку, не смотрит ли этот сайт бот - https://toster.ru/q/190331 как тут например. И для бота просто не делайте ничего.

Comment: Дело в том что при "классической" проверке в скриптах которые торкают бд (работают с бд, но пользователю ничего не выводят) - при отключенных куках, эта проверка работает не корректно. И я так до конца и не понял почему. Выход такой - в скриптах которые работают с $_POST применять строгую проверку. Тот первый скрипт вначале вопроса. А для других страниц - "классическую" проверку. Проблема еще в том что в скриптах которые работаю с $_POST есть защита от CSRF атак. Поэтому редирект на такой скрипт выдаст "csrf detect".

Comment: можете попытаться %) понять проблемы и решение. Пришлось самому ответить на вопрос.

Comment: В чем смысл этих действий? Установить куку `ct` и все?

Comment: смысл ПРОВЕРИТЬ ПОДДЕРЖКУ СЕССИЙ У КЛИЕНТА. Я ниже уже ответил на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

### Не уверен, что при беглом просмотре всем будет всё понятно, но решение я нашел.

Все решение занимает 25 или 26 строк БЕЗ комментариев.Возможно кому-то пригодится.

НО всё-таки проблемка осталась: Если после обращения к странице специально "руками" удалить куки, то при обновлении страницы будет сообщение об ошибке. Я ниже об этом напишу.

1. Скрипт "классической" проверки (см в вопросе) для проверки поддержки кук у клиента НЕ ПРИГОДЕН для проверок в скриптах которые работают с `$_POST`, потому что в такой проверке присутствует редирект на себя.

В скриптах, работающих с `$_POST` есть проверка на CSRF атаку, поэтому "классика" отпадает, потому что будет выдано сообщение о csrf-атаке. В этих скриптах идет вызов `cooki_check(1);` 1 - означает строгую проверку, которая не трогает `$_GET` и не содержит редиректов.

2. Скрипт "классической" проверки кук ТЕРЯЕТ `$_GET`-параметры. Как и что теряет?: Например пользователь щелкает по ссылке подтверждения регистрации в почтовом клиенте или в браузере и скрипт "классической" проверки теряет `$_GET`. Думаю понятно что это из-за редиректа на `PHP_SELF`.

Решение "потери" ГЕТа: В функции проверки куки сохранить ГЕТ и делать редирект на сохраненный ГЕТ.

```
function cooki_check($strict) {
//1 строгая проверка в скриптах которые торкают (изменяют: апдейт, инсерт) бд
//0 НЕ строгая в логин, регистрация, показ скинов(?)    
    @session_start();
    switch ($strict) {
    case 0:
        //"классическая" проверка

      $ref = get2str();
        //функия сохранения (и формирования!) рефера для header("Location:....

        //Если массив ГЕТ не пустой, то в коней приписывается &ct=1
        //Результат будет такой /script.php?par1=1&par2=2&p3=3&ct=1

        //Если массив пустой, то приписывется ?ct=1
        //Результ такой /script.php?ct=1


        if (!isset($_COOKIE['ct']) and ! isset($_GET['ct'])) {
        //если НЕустановлена кука _И_ ГЕТ, то это первое обращение к странице
        //Значит нада установить и куку и $_GET['ct']
        //правильный $ref "приходит" из get2str(). Там же есть доплнительные проверки. Думаю что несложно склеить строку из $_GET
        setcookie('ct', 1);

        //и редирект 
        header("Location: $ref");
        exit;

        } elseif (!isset($_COOKIE['ct'])) {
        //если ГЕТ установлен (то есть не первое обращение к странице), проверить куку
        //ВОТ ТУТ И БУДЕТ ОШИБКА ЕСЛИ РУКАМИ УДАЛИТЬ КУКИ, А В СТРОКЕ БРАУЕРА БУДЕТ /SCRIPT.PHP?BLA=BLA&ct=1 (я об этом выше писал)

        //Если кука НЕуст, значит ОТКЛЮЧЕНЫ У КЛИЕНТА
        //сообщить об ошибке
        er(1);

        }

        break;

    case 1:
        //строгая проверка
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['ct'])) {
        //если неустановлена, то устанвоить
        setcookie("ct", 1);
        //и сообщить "обновите стнраницу или вкл куки"
        //НО если куки отключены то кука ct не будет установлена
        //а работать дальше без поддержки сессии не возможна. Поэтому пусть пользователь разрешает\включает куки. По другому никак!
        er(1);
        }
        break;

    default:
        echo 'Unk $strict in cooki_check()';

        break;
    }

    return;    //можно и без ретурна
}
```

Вот такое оно, решение. Я в код напихал подробных комментариев. Возможно кому-то пригодится.

"Неприятность" будет если пользователь сохранит в закладках url с ct=1. При первом обращении будет сообщение о проблеме с куками.

Всё.

**upd**

Нет, не все. Экспериментальным путём выяснил что для Оперы и гуглохрома нужно дописать строчку `setcookie('ct', 1);` перед выводом сообщения об ошибке.

```
 } elseif (!isset($_COOKIE['ct'])) {
        //если ГЕТ установлен (то есть не первое обращение к странице), проверить куку
        //ВОТ ТУТ И БУДЕТ ОШИБКА ЕСЛИ РУКАМИ УДАЛИТЬ КУКИ, А В СТРОКЕ БРАУЕРА БУДЕТ /SCRIPT.PHP?BLA=BLA&ct=1 (я об этом выше писал)

        //Если кука НЕуст, значит ОТКЛЮЧЕНЫ У КЛИЕНТА
        //
        //и снова установить ее. ПОТОМУ что в опере и гуглохроме, при обновлении страницы кука не ставится. Повторно я устанавливаю ее на тот случай, если обращение к странице произошло с браузерной закладки. Но есть некоторые браузеры, которые нихр не умеют.
    setcookie('ct', 1);
        //сообщить об ошибке
        er(1);

        }
```

Comment: Господи. Какой же вы ужас нагородили. Хотите отфильтровать ботов - я вам кинул ссылку как, не проверяйте куки для ботов, а просто пускайте на сайт. Это раз. Во вторых - Зачем вообще эту ерунду городить? Cookie почти всегда включены и используются обычно для авторизации пользователя. Если кто-то выключает Cookie он как бы должен понимать что авторизация не будет работать. Если ваши страницы доступны и любому человеку, зачем ему этот куки? Если доступны только категориям пользователей, почему вы хотите чтобы поисковый бот видел их? Ваш подход мягко говоря странный.

Comment: О ботах я вообще не вспоминал. Вы не поняли о чем я тут спрашивал и какое решение УЖЕ реализовал.

Comment: КУКИ в проэкте у меня вообще не используются. Только одна единственная, для проверки возможности использовать сессию.

Comment: "почему вы хотите чтобы поисковый бот видел их?" - если кука не установлена, то будет выдаваться страница с ошибкой. Вначале я спросил ЕСЛИ неправильно проверять куку, то поисковик будет видеть ТОЛЬКО страницу ошибки или нет? Вообщем история эта понятна только мне. Если кто чего не понимает - спрашивайте. мне охота рассказать, но с чего начать??? не хочу все  в кучу лепить.Хотя я уже все написал. Возможно не понятно(?) Готов разьяснить каждую строчку.